# is it possible to test a USSD application local machine before you deploy?

Tags: php, testing, local, ussd

I want to start on developing an application ussd.mais I 'd like to know if there is a way to test it on my local machine in the same way for web site with WampServer before deployement .

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is coming a year late but it could help someone else so i will still post it. you can use http://africastalking.com they have a very easy to use platform. Just discovered them and am using them for my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Restcomm USSD Gateway as it contains a simulator. See Documentation at http://documentation.telestax.com/core/tutorials/running-USSD-push-example.html#ussd

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to test your USSD application on your local machine, but it largely depends on the gateway you're using. While some aggregators offer USSD simulators, others don't. A few Simulators out there are:

- http://www.ideamart.lk/idea-pro/start-up-the-simulator
- https://github.com/smsgh/ussd-mocker